# "no such colum : time (Code 1)" SQLiteException in android studio

Tags: android, database, sqlite

onCreate method of the database :

```
private static String DATABASE = "DB1.db";
private static String TABLE ="NotesTable";
private static String TITLE = "title";
private static String NAME ="name";
private static String TIME = "time";
private static String BOOKMARK = "bookm";
private static String NOTITIME = "notitime";


DatabaseHelper(Context context) {
    super(context, DATABASE, null, 1);
}

@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE "
            + TABLE + "( "
            + TITLE + " TEXT, "
            + NAME + " TEXT, "
            + NOTITIME + " LONG, "
            + BOOKMARK + " INTEGER DEFAULT 1 )");
}
```

Error occurs in the following code of the database :

```
//cursor to get all the column's data 
List<DataModel> getdata(){

    List<DataModel> data=new ArrayList<>();
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    StringBuilder stringBuffer = new StringBuilder();
    DataModel dataModel;

    @SuppressLint("Recycle") Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery("select * from "+TABLE+" ORDER BY " + TIME + " DESC;",null);


    while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
        dataModel= new DataModel();

        String title = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow("title"));
        String name = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow("name"));
        Long time = cursor.getLong(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow("time"));
        Integer book = cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow("bookm"));
        Long notitime = cursor.getLong(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow("notitime"));

        dataModel.setTitle(title);
        dataModel.setName(name);
        dataModel.setDate(time);
        dataModel.setBookmark(book);
        dataModel.setNotiTime(notitime);

        stringBuffer.append(dataModel);

        data.add(dataModel);
    }
    return data;
}
```

StackTrace :

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
              Process: com.tank.vishal.sample, PID: 5981
              java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.tank.vishal.sample/com.tank.vishal.sample.MainActivity}: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such column: time (code 1): , while compiling: select * from NotesTable ORDER BY time DESC;
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2817)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2892)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(Unknown Source:0)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1593)
                  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:105)
                  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6541)
                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                  at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:240)
                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:767)
               Caused by: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such column: time (code 1): , while compiling: select * from NotesTable ORDER BY time DESC;
                  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.nativePrepareStatement(Native Method)
                  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.acquirePreparedStatement(SQLiteConnection.java:889)
                  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.prepare(SQLiteConnection.java:500)
                  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteSession.prepare(SQLiteSession.java:588)
                  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteProgram.<init>(SQLiteProgram.java:58)
                  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteQuery.<init>(SQLiteQuery.java:37)
                  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDirectCursorDriver.query(SQLiteDirectCursorDriver.java:44)
                  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.rawQueryWithFactory(SQLiteDatabase.java:1318)
                  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.rawQuery(SQLiteDatabase.java:1257)
                  at com.tank.vishal.sample.DatabaseHelper.getdata(DatabaseHelper.java:102)
                  at com.tank.vishal.sample.MainActivity.initViews(MainActivity.java:114)
                  at com.tank.vishal.sample.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:83)
                  at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6975)
                  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1213)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2770)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2892) 
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(Unknown Source:0) 
                  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1593) 
                  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:105) 
                  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164) 
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6541) 
                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                  at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:240) 
                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:767)
```

**What I've tried :**

Changing the name of table and database,
Uninstalling the app itself and remove all the data from device.

this error never occurred before while making this app, it was running perfectly till today.

P.S. - I tried installing the app in a device in which it is not installed before NOT EVEN ONCE and it returned below error :

```
Failure [INSTALL_CANCELED_BY_USER]
```

$ adb shell pm uninstall com.tank.vishal.sample
DELETE_FAILED_INTERNAL_ERROR
Error while Installing APK

Answer (score 0):

Your `CREATE TABLE` SQL does not create a column with the name of `time`. First add the column specification for it and only then uninstall and reinstall your app.

Comment: Omg one silly mistake and look what happens , thank you very much for pointing it out, sir.

Answer (score 0):

In **onCreate**, you didn't create column **time**

Comment: Appreciate your help thnx, sir.